# How to fetch data asynchronously inside component and pass it as props to another component in render?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react app and I would like to fetch some data asynchronously, process it, change the current components state, and then pass it as props to another component in the render. I tried fetching it in componentWillMount, but seems like the render still happens before data is fetched. What is a working solution for that? I also tried fetching the data in a ES6 contructor, and the issue still persists.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well an ideal place to fetch the data would be the `componentWillMount` function, however because of the async nature your child component may get rendered before the data is fetched and hence you can do two things.

Maintain a loading state that doesn't render the component till the result is fetched, like:

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        // other states
   }
}

componentWillMount() {
    //your async request here
}

render() {
   if(this.state.isLoading) {
       return null; // or you can render laoding spinner here
   } else {
       return (
           //JSX here with the props
       )
   } 
}
```

Other way is to have an empty prop and perform for a check in the child component:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        someProps: null; 
    }
} 

componentWillMount() {
     //your async request here
}

render() {

    return (
         <Child someProps={this.state.someProps}/>
    )    
}
```

**Child**

```
render() {

  if(this.props.someProps == null) 
        return null;
  else {
      return (//JSX contents here);
  }
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer the first method

Comment: For some reason, my unit tests are failing now though. The basic test to render the object without crashing fails. How is it related to the solution above, and what do I do to fix them?

Comment: Maybe you haven't handled the loading condition, I don't have much idea of unit test, so I may not be able to help you.

Comment: Could you accept this as an answer if it helped and ask another for the unit test if you can't figure that out

Comment: Sure :) Thanks! Sorry,  I'm new to using StackOverflow, still figuring out how it works

Comment: The child method is handy if you want to render other components before the data is loaded. Thanks :)